# Are there any sites you can use to develop an online course for your own conlang?

Tags: tools, conlang-learning

Creating a conlang is usually only half (or less than half!) of the necessary effort: someone has to be able to learn it, unless you want to keep it as your own private secret code.

I use Duolingo to learn various languages, and it does of course have an Esperanto course on it, as well as Klingon and High Valyrian. However, it is unlikely that it will feature many more Conlangs, especially not one that you will develop yourself.

Now, it is of course not feasible to re-implement all of Duolingo's features, but I was just wondering if there are any apps/websites that you can use to develop an on-line course for your own conlang (it has to be fully automated, with no human teaching involved).

Is there something along the lines of Duolingo available where you can create your own courses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently folks can do this with Memrise, as evidenced by the [Sajem Tan lessons](https://www.memrise.com/course/1372467/sajem-tan/).

There's been talk that I found on Duolingo forums, but if they're at all serious, they probably won't allow "dabbling". You'd need a serious effort to make and maintain enough lessons for people to actually learn a language.

Comment: I notice they have several toki pona courses...

Answer (score 2):

[Elon.io](https://elon.io/) lets you make your own lessons and courses. It spaces your repetition of each word/phrase based on how often you have been getting it right. It provides computer pronunciation options based on real world languages, as well as statistics on your set of words and performance.

Comment: Don't worry, necrobumping isn't a concept that really applies to the SE network. Questions regularly get new answers years after they were asked, and this one's only a month old!

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Elon terms of service only allows use by those who reside or are situated in the Milky Way, so it's not universally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using YouTube.

Advantage- There are a lot of people on YouTube that could see your course.

Disadvantage- This is a double-edged sword. You may not get many views since there are so many people and your video could get lost among the sea of videos.

Another platform is Udemy.

Advantage- It gives you look and feel of an actual course, and if you get 1000 people on Udemy for a $10 course (let's say it's a 50/50 split between you and Udemy) you get $5000.
But you need 1000 subscribers AND 4000 hour watchtime (your subscribers need to be interested and you can't be just  another YouTuber they subscribed to) just to start making ads. And those ads pay when someone clicks on them.

Disadvantage- Let's be real, many people just want the freebies. And even if someone is interested in your course, Udemy is probably having some discount for your course.